# Embedding build time into JAR Manifest using Ant

Tags: java, ant, manifest, build-time

If I want to embed the current time in JAR manifest using ant is there an ant property I can use for "now" and which manifest attribute is the best to put this information?

I currently have the following

```
  <manifest>
    <attribute name="Signature-Title" value="${project.name}"/>
    <attribute name="Signature-Version" value="${release.version}"/>
    <attribute name="Signature-Vendor" value="XXX"/>
    <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
  </manifest>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [tstamp task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html) for this.

```
 <tstamp>
    <format property="TODAY" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />
  </tstamp>

  <manifest>
    <attribute name="Signature-Title" value="${project.name}"/>
    <attribute name="Signature-Version" value="${release.version}"/>
    <attribute name="Signature-Vendor" value="XXX"/>
    <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
    <attribute name="Built-Date" value="${TODAY}"/>
  </manifest>
```

This task set three properties (DSTAMP, TSTAMP, and TODAY) with the current timestamp, each in a different default format (check the link). With the nested `format` node, you can define a custom format for any of them.

Comment: It's worth noting that embedding the built time in the MANIFEST will cause the WAR to be rebuilt _every time_ even if nothing at all has changed; not very clean IMO.

Answer (score 0):

**Use UTC format only** in `jar`or `war` META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (don't use localized date/time without TZ because you will lost TimeZone information).

See [How to have Maven show local timezone in maven.build.timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281988/how-to-have-maven-show-local-timezone-in-maven-build-timestamp/47591695#47591695)