# How to have Maven show local timezone in maven.build.timestamp?

Tags: java, maven, timezone

In Maven 3.2.2+, the `maven.build.timestamp` has been redefined to show the time in UTC, as per [MNG-5452](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5452).

Is there any way to specify that I want the timezone info in my local timezone and not in UTC?  I briefly browsed the maven sources, but do not see anyway to specify that I want the TZ to be local TZ and not UTC based.

Answer (score 32):

As already mentioned, in the current versions of Maven (at least up to version 3.3.+), the `maven.build.timestamp` property does not allow for timezone overrides.

However, if you are okay with utilizing a different property name for your purposes, the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/timestamp-property-mojo.html) allows you to configure custom timestamps for a variety of purposes. Here is an example to configure the current timestamp in EST during a build.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>timestamp-property</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>timestamp-property</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <name>build.time</name>
                        <pattern>MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa</pattern>
                        <locale>en_US</locale>
                        <timeZone>America/Detroit</timeZone>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Then you can utilize the `${build.time}` property instead of `${maven.build.timestamp}` where you need a timestamp of the build in your preferred timezone.

Comment: You say  "... the maven.build.timestamp property does allow for timezone overrides". Did you mean to say does **not** allow for timezone overrides?

Comment: :) thanks for that. Took me a while of searching the page to realise

Comment: This timezone notation didn't work for me `<timeZone>MEZ</timeZone>`, I need to use `<timeZone>Europe/Zurich</timeZone>`

Comment: Wow, been a minute since I've been to this answer. Yeah, I later found a similar issue with EST not working how I'd like and ended up switching to America/Detroit instead too. Editing my answer to accommodate. Thanks!

Comment: If you are looking for code for your time zone try here, those worked for me
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: This not always solve thee problem. In my case I use timestamp as directory name when build release versions so I can keep older ones if needed.

Comment: In my case, timezone only works when specified like this `GMT+04:00`

Comment: The best answer is this: It should be mark as the best one. Thanks for sharing @alexanderific

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no pure Maven solution but you can use an Ant task.

Following the instructions given in the [Maven plugin developers cookbook](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/add-build-time-to-manifest.html), you can generate a `filter.properties` file with the `<tstamp>` ant task. In this element, you can customize your timestamp with the same date/time pattern as the [SimpleDateFormat class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and also use the [Timezone class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html). You can then use `${build.time}`, by default it will use your local timezone.

**1)Use the maven-antrun-plugin**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <!-- Safety -->
            <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}"/>
            <tstamp>
              <format property="last.updated" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"/>
            </tstamp>
            <echo file="${basedir}/target/filter.properties" message="build.time=${last.updated}"/>
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**2)Activate filtering**

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
</resources>
<filters>
  <filter>${basedir}/target/filter.properties</filter>
</filters>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no solution but to workaround. Do you happened to use maven [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html) plugin?
If so, you can use it to generate revision for you and build timestamp. This timestamp will be with based on your local java time zone configuration.

Edit: Nevertheless question is about `timestamp`, as [Dean Schulze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34372/dean-schulze) pointed out, only first `execution` will break `${buildNumber}`. To fix that you'll have to add another `execution` to your configuration that will create `buildRevision`. Updated example, below.
For ex.:`

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
<inherited>true</inherited>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>generate-timestamp</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>create</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <format>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z}</format>
            <items>
                <item>timestamp</item>
            </items>
            <buildNumberPropertyName>buildDateTime</buildNumberPropertyName>
            <getRevisionOnlyOnce>true</getRevisionOnlyOnce>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>generate-buildnumber</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>create</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <revisionOnScmFailure>0</revisionOnScmFailure>
            <useLastCommittedRevision>true</useLastCommittedRevision>
            <buildNumberPropertyName>buildRevision</buildNumberPropertyName>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Than you can use `${buildDateTime}` where you want to inject your timestamp variable. Another execution with the same goal will store you revision as well.

Comment: This overwrites the `${buildNumber}`

Comment: I edited, and added another execution that will create correct `buildRevision`

Answer (score 0):

What I did but might not apply to other people though, is that I export an environment variable in bash like

```
buildtimestamp=$(date +%H:%M)
```

and then consume it in the pom.xml when building my project.

```
<properties>
    <timestamp>${buildtimestamp}</timestamp>
</properties>
```